# sending an unknown object through an intent without breaking it down

Tags: android, android-intent, parcel

I'm trying to send an object through an intent. From all the examples I've seen, it needs to be parcelable, and have all its sub-fields written to the parcel. Meaning that ultimately it is broken down to its ints, strings, etc. Is there a way to pass an object through an intent without all of this? Just send the object, have the receiving activity take it out of the intent, and then take whatever needed information it needs from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to get away with it, just by making the object serializable, but based on the object complexion, it could cause performance issues, other than that, there's no way to send a plain object the way you want, Intent bases its objects transfer on Inter Process Communication Protocol, which requires encode objects into more primitive values and send it to another end point and then decode them.

Hope this helps.

Regards!

Comment: How do I make my object serializable? Everywhere I looked, it says that I need to create a class that implements serializable - but I don't have access to this object's code, and can't change it. Can this be done via a class that extends this object and implements serializable?

Comment: I found some online code that wraps my object with a serializable class, that just about solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You have to implement an interface called `Parelable` and write your object's instances inside a parcel.

Have a look at this tutorial

http://www.codexperience.co.za/post/passing-an-object-between-activities-using-an-intent

Comment: I mentioned this in the question, I'm not looking for parcelable